# IE9 - Check Server Connection Status

Tags: ajax, connection, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to check the connection status with the server, within an ajax call in IE9, ?

Im using this in browsers that support XHR:

```
AJS.$.ajax({
    url : "path_to_server",
    type : 'DELETE',
    async:false,
    data:JSON.stringify(resquestData)
}).done(function(){
    doSomething();
}).fail(function(response,textStatus, xhr){
    if(xhr.code == 19){ // where i check if it is a NetworkError
      alert("connection lost");
    }else{
        alert("error");
    }
}
);
```

My problem is that i can't make this solution works in IE9 (or less) because the browser doesn't support xhr ( XmlHttpRequest). Any Solution ?

Best regards

[edit]

i tried create an ActiveXobject before the ajax function:

```
AJS.$("#import").click(function() {
    var xmlhttpie;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlhttpie = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttpie = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                xmlhttpie = false;
            }
        }
    }
     AJS.$.ajax({
       url : "path_to_server",
       type : 'DELETE',
       async:false,
       data:JSON.stringify(resquestData)
     }).done(function(){
           doSomething();
     }).fail(function(response,textStatus, xhr){
           if(xhr.code == 19){ // where i check if it is a NetworkError
             alert("connection lost");
           }else{
              alert("error");
           }
    }
);
}
```

but when debugging (inside Ajax function) in IE9 i get this (where "A" is the xmlhttpie) :

link -> http://prntscr.com/4o9grh

Answer (score 1):

Just give a url in your ajax call and check, What it returns.

```
$.ajax('url', {
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('Not connected to server');
    },
    200: function() {
      alert('Connected');
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you George i will try that

Comment: are you able to execute any ajax in your application